# ubuntu unknown process running on top - .chopshop?

Tags: ubuntu

I just ran the top command on my ubuntu EC2 instance.

I saw that there is a process named .chopshop that use 300% of my cpu.

I killed it, but how do I know what the process is and how do i prevent it from re-running ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @yoonix why do you think it has been compromised ?

Comment: Maybe it's https://github.com/MITRECND/chopshop ?

Comment: @adiuva I also thought about it just didn't know where could it come from